# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Instance Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to just change the instance type in AWS EBS using the cli?, we would like to keep a larger instance type during peak business hours but then downgrade to a lower instance type during non peak hours.

Set instance type to c3.large during the day
Reset instance type to t2.medium during the night.

Comment: Its currently possible from the web console, but we would like to automate the same using cron scheduler.

Comment: It is easier to change the number of instances using [Time-based Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html#using-features.managing.as.timebased), which directly serves the scheduled peak business hours requirement.  Is that possible for you?

Comment: @James that is possible for us, it will work well. But was just looking at saving up more costs by reducing the instance size too. Instead of running a m1.medium for 750 hrs with autoscale, would like to split 60/40 % where we use a m1.medium for 60% and during night we used a m1.small or a t2.small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using the `modify-instance-attribute` command. Taken from the aws cli [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-attribute.html):

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-5203422c --instance-type "{\"Value\": \"m1.small\"}"
```

However, as @James pointed out in the comment, Time-based scaling might be better solution in your case.